# Nginx with Daphne gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, daphne

I decided to replace uwsgi with daphne since I was having issues with Django Channels and uwsgi. After following [this](http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne/) tutorial. I configured my nginx this way in sites-enabled. Most of the other examples I have come across are not using daphne so I could not relate to them.

```
 server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      80;
        server_name .MyDomain.com;
        charset     utf-8;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            # your Django project's media files - amend as required
            alias /home/ec2-user/MyDomainVenv/MyDomainWeb/media;
        }

        location /static {
            # your Django project's static files - amend as required
            alias /home/ec2-user/MyDomainVenv/MyDomainWeb/static;
        }


            location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }
    }
```

I started Daphne using this way

```
daphne main.asgi:channel_layer
```

and a worker thread using

```
python manage.py runworker
```

This is my asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main.settings")

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

any suggestions on what might be going wrong ?

I tried accessing my website and this is what i got

```
==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2019/03/23 07:13:21 [error] 22191#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.231.182.18, server: MyDomain.com, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8001/admin/", host: "www.MyDomain.com"

==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
71.231.182.18 - - [23/Mar/2019:07:13:21 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

This is what I get when I start daphne

```
daphne main.asgi:channel_layer
Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1, channel layer main.asgi:channel_layer.
HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel layer
Listening on endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Please check your django logs for the exact reason for the error. Nginx logs aren't much help in this case.

Comment: Have you tried running this `daphne main.asgi:channel_layer` in the console? Did it go well? I doubt.

Comment: @spiritsree yes it is running and successfull

Comment: Moreover, `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001` is channels running on port 8001? What is running on port 8001?

Comment: I think channel layer is on 8000. I updated the post with output of daphne

Comment: Ok i think i need to start daphne this way `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 main.asgi:channel_layer`

Comment: @spiritsree YES it worked.  Can you put that as the answer. My daphne was at the wrong port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`daphne` is running behind `nginx`. So, you need to add that as an upstream to your nginx conf.

Assuming that `daphne` is running on port 8001 and `django` application on 80

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server 0.0.0.0:8001;
}
```

and update as

```
proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
```